# Laravel: How to get GlobalScopes list of a Model?

Tags: php, laravel, builder

I wonder how do we can get list of all globalScopes of a Model.

Assume we have these globalScopes for User model:

```php
class User extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    protected static function boot()
    {
        self::addGlobalScope(new UserTypeScope());

        self::addGlobalScope(new UserStatusScope());

    }
}
```

Now I want to get a list of all GlobalScopes for User model.

```php
// I want a way to get the name of that two Scope classes

$scopes = User::getScopes();

// $scopes should have UserTypeScope and UserStatusScope
```

Any help would be great appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$scopes = (new User())->getGlobalScopes();
```

Or

```
public static function listGlobalScopes()
{
    return (new self())->getGlobalScopes();
}
```